# Export WindowsForm with images and files

Tags: c#, file, export

Well, I don't if I asked well this question because I have the next problem:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvO8y.png)

As you can see here, in one of my many WindowsForms I read a specific file.exe as well with file.txt with their own directions, when I run this (Debug) it works perfectly fine because the Folder that storage those files are inside of \WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\bin\Debug.
Maybe the worst idea, because I want to 'release' this project, once I do this, I get a lot of errors of missing files (Because of the folder) except with certain images that I imported to Resources.rex.
Any suggestion?, like how can I keep all those .txt files with the .exe files, and still reading and running them when I use 'release' from Visual Studio

**EDIT:**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbG9J.png)
This is the Release version, some images are intact but when I try to read the .txt files or Run the .exe files I get this message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created exe for that, best suggestion that store those files in C drive as there will be no such folder of debug or release when you export exe. And even instance will be running from another folder which may be not same as you have provided folder path in your application. You should provide a path of folder, if that path is not present then create the folder as below.

```
string folderPath = "C:\\YourFolderPath\\";
if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
 {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
 }
```

This may solve the issue but it is not still correct way to do.